# Wubi installation problem: Coud not find the ISO /ubuntu/install/kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: kubuntu, wubi

I've got a Lenovo ThinkPad T450.

I want to install Linux inside my current Windows 7 installation, preferably Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I install Kubuntu with Wubi 16.04.3r325 (wubi16043r325.exe) by Hakuna. Which I've downloaded from https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases
When the Windows firewall asks me to allow pyrun.exe, I choose: Allow access for private networks.
Then Wubi starts downloading kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.
Then Wubi tells me to reboot to complete the installation.
So far, so good.
But when I reboot...

I get:

```
Completing the Ubuntu installation
[0.114484] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[6.063611] tmp tmp0: A TPM error (6) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
[6.123616] tmp tmp0: A TPM error (6) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
```

Then I get a nice graphical Kubunu installation screen with Kubunu logo.

Then the shell comes back with the following error message:

```
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubunutu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) build-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
Coud not find the ISO /ubuntu/install/kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

When I login to Windows, then the file c:\ubuntu\install\kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso exists.
I ran chkdsk /r several times.
I tried to install Ubuntu instead.
I tried to install the latest version (17.10) of Kubuntu and Ubuntu instead of the LTS.
I tried the workaround to install the 32-bit version of Kubuntu by selecting the WUBI distro and then copying all the missing files during the installation.
But nothing worked.

There is also no /ubuntu directory (so also not a /ubuntu/install directory).

I tried to mount /dev/sda1 with the following command, to see if I can access the c:\ubuntu\install\kubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso file from there:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows-ntfs
```

But when I type

```
ls /mnt/windows-ntfs
```

I see:

```
_SMSTVolumeID....... <--- a long id
System Volume Information
bootmgr
boot
```

Instead of the files on my Windows C:\ drive....

The output of the command

```
blkid
```

is:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID=" ...a long id... " TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="...-01  <--- a ID
/dev/sda2: PARTUUID="...-02  <--- a ID
```

I can't find any efi directory.

```
ls /sys
```

as well as

```
ls /sys/firmware
```

don't show an efi directory

So my Lenovo ThinkPad T450 laptop did not boot in EFI mode, but Legacy BIOS mode.

I don't have the administrator password for my BIOS. So I can't change any settings there. But I can read the BIOS settings. The BIOS of my Lenovo Thinkpad T450 is configured as:

```
UEFI Secure Boot: Disabled
Intel Rapid Start Technology: Enabled

Network Boot: PCI LAN: IBA GE
UEFI/Legacy Boot: Both
UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority: Legacy First
CSM Support: Yes
Boot Mode: Quick

Boot Priority Order:
    1. AATA HDD0 LITEON LCH-128VS2
    2. ATA HADD1
    3. ATA HDD2
    4. PCI LAN IBA GE Slot 00C8 v1553

Excluded from boot priority order:
    * USB CD
    * USB FDD
    * USB HDD

Flash BIOS updating by end-users: Enabled
```

How can I use Linux on my Lenovo ThinkPad T450?

---

Update:

I tried the solutions given so far on https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues/80

```
ls /isodevice
```

shows that /isodevice exists, but is empty.
So I did:

mount -t ntfs /dev/sda1 /isodevice

To check if the iso can be found I did:

```
ls /isodevice/ubuntu/install/installation.iso
```

But it wasn't there.

```
ls /isodevice
```

shows

```
_SMSTVolumeID....... <--- a long id
System Volume Information
bootmgr
boot
```

so I just did, crossing my fingers and then type:

```
exit
```

to try again.
But that resulted in the same error message:

```
Could not find the installation files /ubuntu/install/custom-installation
```

Hopefully a working solution will be posted on https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues/80 soon :-)

---

This question is different from "Why doesn't Ubuntu 16.04 have ubuntu.exe inside the iso?", because:
"Why doesn't Ubuntu 16.04 have ubuntu.exe inside the iso?" expains why wubi / ubuntu.exe inside the iso. The explenation is that wubi is officially not supported anymore.

Although Wubi is officially not supported anymore. It is continued by Hakuna.
And my questions is not about "why isn't ubuntu.exe not in the iso anymore", but: How can I install Linux on my ThinkPad T450?

Comment: wubi is no longer supported , it has not been supported for quite some time and is not recommended. If you wish to use it anyways you will need to file a bug report from wherever you obtained the program, github perhaps.

Comment: Please add the output of `fdisk -l` and `parted -l` to your question. As I read [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues/80) the script with the error message is part of the used ISO and not part of Wubi or Wubiuefi. BTW: a partition with label "System Reserved" is probably a hidden partition and Windows C drive is sda2 or another partition which is not recognized by the ISO programs.

Comment: Thnx ngng. I tried the solutions given so far on https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/issues/80 Unfortunately the things posted so far don't work yet...

Comment: @ngng fdisk -l and parted -l both result in command not found (fdisk: not found and parted: not found).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I don't see the question anymore without logging in. I meant that you boot into ISO live system to run `fdisk -l ` and `parted -l`. Try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie) to burn a pendrive. If it doesn't work, ask your question without Wubi relation. There are a lot of users who don't understand your problem if they read something about Wubi.